# Adding a tab to the QGIS project properties

Tags: qgis, python, qt-designer

I would like to know, if there is the possibility to add new tabs to the QGIS project properties? (for example, under the "QGIS Server")

The goal is to have the advanced options of a QGIS plugin directly in the project properties.

[image: QGIS project properties]